# How can I send an image from an sql database to an android client?

Tags: php, android, sql, image

I'm trying to  send an image from an sql database to an android client. I'm doing this by way of a php middleman. The code stops working due to a null returning of the method below. 
My php code(works fine to encode image into base64(decoded the encoding and it worked)):

```
<?php
    //get image
    function ob_base64_encode($c) {
    $a=base64_encode($c);
    $arr = array('base64' => $a);
      return json_encode($arr);
    }
    $image=resize(48,80,$image);
    // And pass its name as a string
    ob_start('ob_base64_encode');
    imagepng($image);
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

My android code:

```
public static Bitmap getIm(String IP, int height, int width)
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//Network queries and gets response(works)
    String result = Network.getResponse(IP, nameValuePairs);
//manually decode string since for some reason JSON decode won't work(also works)
String r=result.split(":\"")[1];
r=r.split("\"")[0];
//decode string
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(r, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
    return decodedByte;
//returns null
    }
```